# Does 'statsmodels' or another Python package offer an equivalent to R's 'step' function?

Tags: r, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels, model-fitting

Is there a `statsmodels` or other Python equivalent for R's [`step`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/step.html) functionality for selecting a formula-based model using [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I really suspect that you are doing the same online course as I do -- the following allows you to get the right answers. If the task at hand is not very computationally heavy (and it isn't in the course), then we can sidestep all the smart details of the `step` function, and just try all the subsets of the predictors.

For each subset we can calculate [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) as `ACI = 2*nvars - 2*result.llf`.
And then we just find a subset with the minimal AIC:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
AICs = {}
for k in range(1,len(predictorcols)+1):
    for variables in itertools.combinations(predictorcols, k):
        predictors = train[list(variables)]
        predictors['Intercept'] = 1
        res = sm.OLS(target, predictors).fit()
        AICs[variables] = 2*(k+1) - 2*res.llf
pd.Series(AICs).idxmin()
```

Comment: Good approach. In the end I just did it in R and copied over the model into Python.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer didn't work for me but the below one did. Heavily copied from Kostya.

```
AICs = {}
for k in range(1,len(predictorcols)+1):
    for variables in itertools.combinations(predictorcols, k):
        predictors = list(variables)
        i = True
        independent =''
        for p in predictors:
            if i:
                independent = p
                i=False
            else:
                independent+='+ {}'.format(p)
        regresion = '$DependentVariable$ ~ {}'.format(independent)
        res = sm.ols(regresion, data=train).fit()
        AICs[variables] = 2*(k+1) - 2*res.llf
pd.Series(AICs).idxmin()
```